# Masterpage and different folders

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a page which I wanted to connect to a `masterpage` in a different folder then the page, and the `masterpage` doesn't work.

How can I connect it to the `masterpage` when it still stays that way that they aren't in the same folder?

It will be really messy if I will have to take all the pages out of their folders.

Here is the connection line:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="eeSettings.aspx.cs" Inherits="employee_eeSettings" %>
```

Tnx for the help :D

EDIT:
i discribe it good, the masterpage is in no folder and the and the page which i want to connect to the masterpage is in a folder.
the problem is that when the page is in a folder the masterpage's css(its in a styleSheet) is not working, and when i take it out of the folder it does work.

Comment: Where would you like to move it to? Please give us the folder structure.

Comment: Can you say what error you're getting?

Comment: i edited the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @DaveMroz's answer, you need to specify absolute virtual path to your css file:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Styles.css") %>' />
```

Comment: Well...he went and changed the question after I posted my response!  It had nothing to do with the MasterPage path, but he really was talking about the CSS reference!  argh... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can refenrece any folder as long as it's part of the project. Start with a tilde to indicate the root of the project and then put in whatever folder structure you need.

```
MasterPageFile="~/Folder/Subfolder/MasterPage.master"
```

Comment: i discribe it good, the masterpage is in no folder and the and the page which i want to connect to the masterpage is in a folder.

Comment: Then your original code will work. The ~/ indicates to start at the root, so even if your page is in /folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/page.aspx, the reference to the MasterPage would still be ~/MasterPage.Master